# Highcharter shiny events - Returning multiple selected points to a dataframe

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny

Is there a way to return all the selected points from a scatter plot in **highchart** via shiny? The idea is to dynamically exclude or include points to be used for regression. I would like to have the ability to select the desired points, write them to a dataframe and then perform a non-linear regression on them. So far, I'm able to select and deselect points from the chart by using the JavaScript code from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-selection-points/) and [here](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/master/vignettes/shiny-events-demo.Rmd). I can't seem to be able to return the selected points to a dataframe.
Please see my attempt below.

```
#devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
library(highcharter) 
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shiny)

#http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-selection-points/

# selectPointsByDrag
s1 <- JS("/**
         * Custom selection handler that selects points and cancels the default zoom behaviour
         */
         function selectPointsByDrag(e) {

         // Select points
         Highcharts.each(this.series, function (series) {
         Highcharts.each(series.points, function (point) {
         if (point.x >= e.xAxis[0].min && point.x <= e.xAxis[0].max &&
         point.y >= e.yAxis[0].min && point.y <= e.yAxis[0].max) {
         point.select(true, true);
         }
         });
         });

         // Fire a custom event
         Highcharts.fireEvent(this, 'selectedpoints', { points: this.getSelectedPoints() });

         return false; // Don't zoom
         }")

# unselectByClick
s2 <- JS("/**
         * On click, unselect all points
         */
         function unselectByClick() {
         var points = this.getSelectedPoints();
         if (points.length > 0) {
         Highcharts.each(points, function (point) {
         point.select(false);
         });
         }
         }")


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("selection_ui"),
    highchartOutput("plot_hc"),
    tableOutput("view") 

  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    df <- data.frame(x = 1:50, y = 1:50, otherInfo = letters[11:15])
    df_copy <- df

    output$plot_hc <- renderHighchart({

      highchart() %>%
        hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy', events = list(selection = s1, click = s2)) %>%
        hc_add_series(df, "scatter") %>%
        hc_add_event_point(event = "select")


    })

    output$view <- renderTable({
      data.table(x = input$plot_hc_select$x, y = input$plot_hc_select$y)
    })

    observeEvent(input$plot_hc, print(paste("plot_hc", input$plot_hc)))

    output$selection_ui <- renderUI({

      if(is.null(input$plot_hc_select)) return()

      wellPanel("Coordinates of selected point: ",input$plot_hc_select$x, input$plot_hc_select$y)

    })

  }

)
```

> Error: column or argument 1 is NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to achieve what you want, using only Highcharter or Highcharts (as far as I know). One simple way to do this though would be to store each selected point in an (javascript) array, and to pass it to R. Thanks to Shiny, this can be easily done using `Shiny.onInputChange` (see example [here](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/message-javascript-to-r/app.R)).

One could rewrite your shiny app like this to make it work:

1) In the `s1` function, store the selected points in `xArr`.

2) Use `Shiny.onInputChange` to pass `xArr` to R. `xArr` will be accessible via `input$R_xArr` (I chose the name `R_xArr`, it is not an automatic assignment).

3) Use a `reactiveValues` to store the selected points on the R side.

4) Update these values with appropriate observers.

```
#devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
library(highcharter) 
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

# selectPointsByDrag
s1 <- JS("/**
         * Custom selection handler that selects points and cancels the default zoom behaviour
         */
         function selectPointsByDrag(e) {
           var xArr = []
           // Select points
           Highcharts.each(this.series, function (series) {
             Highcharts.each(series.points, function (point) {
               if (point.x >= e.xAxis[0].min && point.x <= e.xAxis[0].max &&
                   point.y >= e.yAxis[0].min && point.y <= e.yAxis[0].max) {
                 xArr.push(point.x);
                 point.select(true, true);

               }
             });
           });
           Shiny.onInputChange('R_xArr', xArr);

           // Fire a custom event
           Highcharts.fireEvent(this, 'selectedpoints', { points: this.getSelectedPoints() });

           return false; // Don't zoom
           }")

# unselectByClick
s2 <- JS("/**
         * On click, unselect all points
         */
         function unselectByClick() {
           var points = this.getSelectedPoints();
           if (points.length > 0) {
             Highcharts.each(points, function (point) {
               point.select(false);
             });
           }
         }")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    highchartOutput("plot_hc"),
    tableOutput("view") 
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    df <- data.frame(x = 1:50, y = 1:50, otherInfo = letters[11:15])

    output$plot_hc <- renderHighchart({
      highchart() %>%
        hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy', events = list(selection = s1, click = s2)) %>%
        hc_add_series(df, "scatter") %>%
        hc_add_event_point(event = "unselect")
    })

    selected.points <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

    output$view <- renderTable({
      if (is.null(selected.points$x) || is.null(selected.points$y)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        data.table(x = selected.points$x, y = selected.points$y)  
      }
    })

    observeEvent(input$R_xArr, {
      selected.points$x <- sort(unique(c(selected.points$x, input$R_xArr)))
      selected.points$y <- df$y[df$x %in% selected.points$x]
    })

    observeEvent(input$plot_hc_unselect, {
      selected.points$x <- NULL 
      selected.points$y <- NULL
    })

  }

)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the help @kluu.  I really appreciate it. I'll go ahead and accept this answer.